# JQuery Load Invalid Security Certificate Error

Tags: jquery, security, ssl, load, certificate

I cannot load a web-page/website with JQuery because the website has an invalid security certificate.
**Is there anyway to forcefully .load a website with an invalid security certificate with JQuery?**

The following error is in my FireFox console:

> *www.example.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed. The certificate is only
>   valid for new.example.com Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER*

My test code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("https://www.example.com");
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Only the user (or a local program) can add an exception in the browser.

Comment: I think you are right. I will have to find another way to scrape the website.

Comment: @FinkAvenue note that if the website you want to scrape is not in the same domain, that website must allow your to read it with CORS headers, for security reason.

Answer (score 0):

download jquery files and make local links, do not use online links from other server.